# Microsoft webchat bot store global data across sessions C#

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I have a webchat bot written in C# and would like to store some information which would be common between different sessions (above conversation and dialogs), and this data be updated after some specific interval. I would like to know how can I store the data which would be accessed globally?

Comment: Is this what I should refer to? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharpechorproperty%2Ccsetagoverwrite%2Ccsetag

Comment: Are you using bot framework SDK v3 or v4 ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for State Storage. If you're using v3 SDK, take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). For v4 SDK, use the link you found to learn about state store [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharpechorproperty%2Ccsetagoverwrite%2Ccsetag).